# Using .jsk client trusts with node.js https?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

There is no real documentation on this when you look it up.  I mostly saw "convert it to PEM" but that is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in fact a keytool wrapper for node.js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-keytool

but it of course is a a wrapper and not very efficient